# Program still hangs after retrieving 100 rows containg CLOBs

Tags: h2

This is the same problem encountered in Release 1.3.165 when retrieving a remote (TCP/IP connection) result set whose rows contain one or more **CLOB**s.  The fix in Release 1.3.166 is to set the cache size for holding the remote **CLOB**s to **SysProperties.SERVER_RESULT_SET_FETCH_SIZE** * 2.  This poses a new problem:

My particular table happens to have 5 **CLOB**s per row so there is no way I can get this to work unless I know to always make calls to *setFetchSize* on the client side with an appropriate small number based on the number of **CLOB**s per row for a given result set.

In Release 1.3.165 when the cache size was set to **SysProperties.SERVER_CACHED_OBJECTS**, I could mentally multiply the default value of **SERVER_RESULT_SET_FETCH_SIZE** by some factor representing the maximum number of **CLOB**s per row I would ever expect to have in any of my result sets and then set **SERVER_CACHED_OBJECTS** accordingly on the server side and forget about it.  This would also allow me to use the default fetch size for all my queries, which presumably would be more efficient. So I have fallen back to 1.3.165.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation that is not so easy to fix I'm afraid. I will change the default size to `SysProperties.SERVER_RESULT_SET_FETCH_SIZE * 5`, but this is only a workaround of course. The real solution is more complicated. One problem is that LOBs need to stay open until the transaction is committed, and the TCP server and client component don't always know when this is the case.

Comment: SysProperties.SERVER_RESULT_SET_FETCH_SIZE * 5 is kind of arbitrary.  Wouldn't it be better just to put it back to SysProperties.SERVER_CACHED_OBJECTS?

Comment: @RonAaaronson I will use `Math.max(SysProperties.SERVER_CACHED_OBJECTS, SysProperties.SERVER_RESULT_SET_FETCH_SIZE * 5)` then, so you can override the value. But it's an open problem that needs to be solved in any case.